# How do I define a Javascript function with a callback in Obj-C?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore to evaluate some simple scripts in my app.  I'm creating a global object and defining some properties on it like so:

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
JSValue *globalObject = [context globalObject];

[globalObject setValue:fields forProperty:@"fields"];
...
```

So then the script can access the values in `fields` and so on.  I'd like scripts to be able to use a function called `lookup`, and I already have an Objective-C implementation for this function.

How do I add a property to the global object which is a function that calls back to my Objective-C method?  I see that there's a function called `JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback`, but that uses the low-level C constructs like `JSObjectRef`s and takes a C function, not an Objective-C block, so I can't make use of `self` inside the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an Objective-C block to a JSContext and it will then behave as a function. That way, your scripts can call back into your iOS code:

```
context[@"factorial"] = ^(int x) {
    int factorial = 1;
    for (; x > 1; x--) {
        factorial *= x;
    }
    return factorial;
};
[context evaluateScript:@"var fiveFactorial = factorial(5);"];
JSValue *fiveFactorial = context[@"fiveFactorial"];
NSLog(@"5! = %@", fiveFactorial);
```

Source: [Bignerdranch](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/)